# If $B$ is an uncountable set and $A$ is a countable set, then prove that $B$ is similar to $B-A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $B$ is an uncountable set and $A$ is a countable set, then  prove that $B$ is similar to $B-A$.

**Attempt**:

Two sets $A$ and $B$ are called similar $\iff$ thee exists a one to one function $F$ whose domain is the set $A$ and whose range is the set $B$.

$B$ is an uncountable set and $A$ is a countable set, then $B-A$ must also be uncountable and hence, an infinite set.

To prove this, let us suppose $B-A$ is countable. Since, $A$ is countable, hence, $(B-A) \cup A$ should also be countable. But $B \subseteq (B-A) \cup A$ should be countable as well which is a contradiction.

Hence, $B-A$ is an uncountable set as well. Now, we need to show that $(B-A) \sim B$.

How do I move ahead? I think we need to define a one-one onto function from $(B-A) \rightarrow B$ but I am not able to think of such a function.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hint: Use the same idea as in Hilbert's hotel. To make room for countably many new guests, take countably many rooms $1,2,3,\ldots$ and move the guests in those rooms to rooms $2,4,6,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed that $B-A$ is uncountable, so you can extract another countable set from it.

Let's say that $B=A\cup (B-A)=A\cup C \cup B' $, where $C$ is countable and $B'$ uncountable, with $C$ and $B'$ disjoint.

It's easy to construct a bijection between $C$ and $A\cup C$, since are both countable sets, so you have a bijection from $C \cup B'=B-A$ and $A\cup C \cup B'=B$

This works if $A\subseteq B$. If this isn't true, then let $A'$ be $A\cap B$, and repeat the same reasoning with $A'$, and it works since $B-A=B-A'$

Comment: Isn't $A \cup (B-A) = A \cup B ?$

Comment: If $A$ isn't included in $B$, sobstitute $A'=A\cap B$ to $A$, and the same reasoning works

Comment: okay .. I understood till the point that there is a bijection between $C$ and $A \cup C$. But, how does this ensure bijection between $C \cup B'$ and $A \cup C \cup B'$?

Comment: $A$, $C$ and $B'$ are disjoint sets, so construct the function that is the identity from $B'$ to $B'$, and goes bijectively from $C$ to $A\cup C$

Comment: $B'$ is an uncountable set but $C$ and $A \cup C$ are countable sets. How can we sure that such a bijection exists? Their cardinalities are different?

Comment: $C$ is an infinite countable set, that is in bijective relation with $\mathbb{N}$, and the same holds for $A\cup C$

Comment: yeah .. I was talking about the bijection between set $B' \rightarrow C$

Comment: why do you want that bijection?
Follow me. You want a bijection between $B-A$ and $B$. 
If $A\subseteq B$, then $B-A=C\cup B'$ and $B=A\cup C\cup B'$, where $A$, $C$ and $B'$ are disjoint sets. So you construct a bijection $B\to B-A$ that goes from $B'$ to $B'$ and from $A\cup C$ to $C$.

Comment: Oh okay .. Got it.. Thank you very much.