# The set of transcendental numbers and the continuum hypothesis

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $T$ be the set of all transcendental numbers. Show |$T$| = |$\Bbb R$|.

Now $T$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$ so clearly |$T$| $\le$|$\Bbb R$|.

But we can also show that $T$ is uncountable. Suppose by contradiction that $T$ is countable. Let $A$ denote the set of all algebraic numbers. I have shown elsewhere that $A$ is countable. Now $A\cup T$ = **R**. Since the union of two countable sets is countable, $A\cup T$ is countable, contradicting that **R** is uncountable. Hence $T$ is uncountable.

Okay so now I'm basically stuck in the undecidability of the continuum hypothesis because I have|$\Bbb N$| < |$T$| $\le$ |$\Bbb R$| = $c$.

Help?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948021/if-b-is-an-uncountable-set-and-a-is-a-countable-set-then-prove-that-b-is?rq=1).

Comment: The question suggested by @J.R. gives you the result that you need, but [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355049/let-a-be-any-uncountable-set-and-let-b-be-a-countable-subset-of-a-prove) has more thorough proofs of the result.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah, that is very nice.

Comment: @Wilson: Thanks!